# How can I prevent IE flashing a black screen before starting an autoplay HTML5 video?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

We have an auto-starting HTML 5 video (WEBM with MP4 fallback) which works great in Chrome and Firefox. On IE versions 9 to 11 the video flashes up a black screen momentarily before the video starts. According to the client they're seeing this black screen for a few seconds which obviously is a poor user experience.

We’ve tried adding a poster attribute to display a holding image before the video starts but apparently they now see the poster image, then the black screen, then the video starts. I can observe this on my local too although the poster image and black screen only occur for a fraction of a second each. Still not good though.

Has anyone had any experience of this? Any ideas how to resolve? This is our video markup:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="https://placehold.it/600x400">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400" alt="Image fallback" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could resolve it, by playing the video after it can be played through. Now there is no half second switching to a black screen before playing the video. Other browsers behave different and it seems that they start the video directly in advance and there is no short interruption.

```
video = document.getElementById("yourvideoid"); // don't autoplay the video
video.oncanplaythrough = function () { video.play(); }; // plays the video
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `preload` attribute and use JavaScript to ensure it's loaded a certain amount before it starts to try and play. Something like this:

```
$(() => {
  $('video').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.on('loadeddata', () {
      this.readyState >= 2 && this.play();
    }
  });
});
```

Since you only see it for a flash locally, but your client sees it for a few seconds (presumably remotely), it's likely that the video doesn't start loading until hitting play, and IE shows a black screen instead of the poster until it has enough buffered.